# What is the origin of the pronunciation difference between 'replicate' (noun) and 'replicate' (verb)?

Tags: english, phonetics, historical-linguistics, ipa, pronunciation

In English, the noun 'replicate' is pronounced with a schwa (ə) at the end while the verb is pronounced with the diphthong 'eɪ'. The same is true for the word 'duplicate'. Is there a more general trend that I am missing here?

I suppose this isn't quite the same question, but it is similar enough I think to combine: why haven't the verb forms collapsed into using the schwa?

Many thanks from a linguistics newbie.

Comment: I don't think I've ever encountered the noun _replicate_: the normal word in my experience is _replica_. But, as you say, _duplicate_ shows the pattern. I'm pretty sure it's part of the pattern that causes the stress to shift in a number of Latinate bisyllabic words in the noun vs. the verb: _project_, _progress_, _research_ (for some speakers).

Comment: Likewise _syndicate_. I forget the name of the rule.

Comment: @Colin Fine, that seems like a sound explanation. Re: replica vs replicate, I've always taken replica to mean an ontologically focused copy and replicate to mean a teleologically focused copy (e.g. a copy of the Mona Lisa would often be called a replica, but a copy of a research study is often called a replicate).